# Problema ARRAY en javascript jquery UNDEFINED

Tags: javascript, jquery

Mi pregunta:
 Tengo la siguiente función dentro de otra función:

```
var ar11;
var ar12;
var ar13;
var ar14;
var ar1 = [27,28,29];
var ar2 = [24,25,26];
var arprin = [ar1[ar12],ar2[ar14]];
function jedi(){
ar11 =  ar1.length;
ar12 =  Math.floor(Math.random()*ar11);
ar13 =  ar2.length;
ar14 =  Math.floor(Math.random()*ar13);
};
var t = setInterval(jedi,1000);
console.log(ar11);
console.log(ar12);
console.log(arprin);
```

Como se nota está bien estructurado la función aleatoria de hecho la variable ar11 cuando la lanzo por el console me da valores de longitud: un 3 por supuesto, al igual que aleatoriamente suelta los valores de ar12 es decir:2,18 y 9 respectivamente. La que tiene el error es arprin que me aparece undefined en la consola, ¿si alguien tiene alguna sugerencia?, es javascript jquery.

Comment: ar12 ni ar14 tienen valor cuando los usa para asignar valor a arprin.  Por eso, ar1[ar12] no tiene valor, y tampoco ar2[ar14].

Comment: Deberían tener el valor aleatorio tanto ar12 y ar14 que seria el resultado del recorrido del array ar1 y ar2 respectivamente,  ¿Que me sugieres para darle ese valor aleatorio adentro del array arprin a ar12 y ar14?

Comment: Deje la declarcón de arprin donde está, pero dar el valor a arprin adentro (y al fin de) jedi()

Comment: Resulta que si funciono muchas gracias por la sugerencia. Tuve que poner como usted lo menciono el valor de la función pero para que pudiera arrancar el array tuve que dejarlo global también debido a que se esta usando en otra función.